# Which MP3 tagging tool for Linux?

Tags: command-line, software-rec, mp3, tagging

Which application would you recommend for Linux to tag MP3s? Under Windows I used to use Tag&Rename and liked it a lot; it works well under Wine, but I want something that runs natively.

Comment: Good 2018 overview: https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/best-mp3-tag-editing-tools-for-linux/

Comment: **tageditor** supports a wide variety of **formats**, and has both a **GUI** and **CLI** interface: https://github.com/Martchus/tageditor

Answer (score 92, accepted):

There are various:

- [easytag](http://easytag.sourceforge.net/) has a lot of options
- [kid3](http://kid3.sourceforge.net/) if you're on a Qt/KDE environment
- `id3v2` or `eyeD3` for the command line
- Generally music players can also edit common tags, f.e. `banshee`, `rhythmbox` or `amarok`

and a lot others, try searching your distributions repository and test some of them.

Comment: Caution using `id3v2` as it does not support unicode and will corrupt the tags of any modern mp3s which use unicode (as mentioned by @user495470 in his answer suggesting `mid3v2` instead)

Comment: `id3v2` now supports unicode

Comment: +1 for eyeD3 - also a Python library by the same name which powers it, and gives you access to more flexibility if you need to drop down a level; also nice Plugin and ad-hoc Python module support.

Answer (score 79):

I mostly use `mid3v2`. You can install it with `sudo apt-get install python-mutagen` in Ubuntu or with `sudo easy_install pip;sudo pip install mutagen` in OS X.

```
$ mid3v2 -h
Usage: mid3v2 [OPTION] [FILE]...

Mutagen-based replacement for id3lib's id3v2.

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose         be verbose
  -q, --quiet           be quiet (the default)
  -e, --escape          enable interpretation of backslash escapes
  -f, --list-frames     Display all possible frames for ID3v2.3 / ID3v2.4
  --list-frames-v2.2    Display all possible frames for ID3v2.2
  -L, --list-genres     Lists all ID3v1 genres
  -l, --list            Lists the tag(s) on the open(s)
  --list-raw            Lists the tag(s) on the open(s) in Python format
  -d, --delete-v2       Deletes ID3v2 tags
  -s, --delete-v1       Deletes ID3v1 tags
  -D, --delete-all      Deletes ID3v1 and ID3v2 tags
  --delete-frames=FID1,FID2,...
                        Delete the given frames
  -C, --convert         Convert tags to ID3v2.4 (any editing will do this)
  -a "ARTIST", --artist="ARTIST"
                        Set the artist information
  -A "ALBUM", --album="ALBUM"
                        Set the album title information
  -t "SONG", --song="SONG"
                        Set the song title information
  -c "DESCRIPTION":"COMMENT":"LANGUAGE", --comment="DESCRIPTION":"COMMENT":"LANGUAGE"
                        Set the comment information
  -g "GENRE", --genre="GENRE"
                        Set the genre or genre number
  -y YYYY[-MM-DD], --year=YYYY[-MM-DD], --date=YYYY[-MM-DD]
                        Set the year/date
  -T "num/num", --track="num/num"
                        Set the track number/(optional) total tracks
You can set the value for any ID3v2 frame by using '--' and then a frame ID.
For example:
        mid3v2 --TIT3 "Monkey!" file.mp3
would set the "Subtitle/Description" frame to "Monkey!".

Any editing operation will cause the ID3 tag to be upgraded to ID3v2.4.
```

`id3v2` and `id3tag` don't support Unicode and `id3tool` and `mp3info` don't support ID3v2.

Comment: I agree that mid3v2 is the most reliable and modern command line tagging tool mentioned here. Should be voted up.

Comment: Agreed. Neither iTunes nor my car player would recognize the tags created by the other tools. This one did it.

Comment: any idea how to add Publisher tag with it

Comment: Note that, for whatever reason, on Debian you have to install python-mutagen to get the binaries - python3-mutagen doesn't put anything in the path.

Answer (score 11):

I just discovered this little program called [puddletag](http://docs.puddletag.net/). It is not as wonderful as Tag & Rename, but it's close enough.

From the [website](http://docs.puddletag.net/):

> puddletag is an audio tag editor (primarily created) for GNU/Linux
>   similar to the Windows program, Mp3tag. Unlike most taggers for
>   GNU/Linux, it uses a spreadsheet-like layout so that all the tags you
>   want to edit by hand are visible and easily editable.
>
> The usual tag editor features are supported like extracting tag
>   information from filenames, renaming files based on their tags by
>   using patterns and basic tag editing.
>
> Then there’re Functions, which can do things like replace text, trim
>   it, do case conversions, etc. Actions can automate repetitive tasks.
>   Doing web lookups using Amazon (including cover art), Discogs (does
>   cover art too!), FreeDB and MusicBrainz is also supported. There’s
>   quite a bit more, but I’ve reached my comma quota.
>
> Supported formats: ID3v1, ID3v2 (mp3), MP4 (mp4, m4a, etc.),
>   VorbisComments (ogg, flac), Musepack (mpc), Monkey’s Audio (.ape) and
>   WavPack (wv).

Comment: Consider including some further explanation of your suggestions or, at least, links to them.

Answer (score 10):

I've been a dedicated user of [Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard) for quite some time. The only cross-platform tagger that feels truly solid. Don't forget MusicBrainz's huge music database.

Answer (score 10):

I use Ex Falso.  It was installed with QuodLibet music player, so I gave it a shot.

I've used it with single files, batches of files... It's pretty intuitive, and best of all, works very well.

Comment: People should be warned that ex falso and quod libet have a non-standart approach to "Album artist" tag. This tag, created in this editor, may be invisible to other players.

Answer (score 10):

I found this thread and decided to use id3tool.  I was only interested in a very light-weight tool, command-line was fine.  Trying to keep my system free of clutter brought on occasionally by weighty GUI-intensive tools.

Installing was super easy on Linux Mint:

```
sudo apt-get install id3tool
```

As far as I remember it didn't require any additional libraries or anything.  To get a full list of the available options:

```
man id3tool
```

To see the current metadata for an mp3 file:

```
id3tool <filename.mp3>
```

Here is the command I used to update quite  afew mp3's:

```
id3tool -t "<song title>" -a "<album name>" -r "<artist name>" -y "<year>" -c <track number, no quotes, just the number, like 1> <filename.mp3>
```

After doing this, I told Banshee to rescan my music library and there were no longer any files in the "Unknown" Category.  Thanks to strangeronyourtrain for this tip!

Comment: I tried id3tool but had some problems. Tags written by id3tool don't seem to be readable by the MAD library in most cases (fails in about 80% of cases).

Comment: id3tool doesn't support the normal id3v2 tags, only the old v1 tags. And it is no longer developed.

Answer (score 7):

For GUI, I suggest [easytag](http://easytag.sourceforge.net/), and you can lookup more [alternatives here](http://alternativeto.net/software/easytag/?platform=linux). For the command line check out `id3v2`, but the alternatives are endless.

Answer (score 6):

I like eyeD3.

But install it from python pip not from apt. apt currently installs 0.6 version but pip installs latest I think. Docs here: https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ .
eyeD3 has good documentation so it's easy to start. Also it has a bunch of useful plugins - try it!

`$ pip install eyeD3`

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I like [TagTool](http://www.tagtool.org/) and [id3tool](http://nekohako.xware.cx/id3tool/). Both are for the command line. I also find Picard useful for music files that exist in the MusicBrainz database.

Answer (score 4):

I would also suggest [lltag](http://home.gna.org/lltag/).

Works on the command line, rather easy and fast. It also supports CDDB.

Comment: It supports reading vorbiscomment and metaflac too.

Answer (score 3):

Audacity has a metadata editing tool, which can be shown when exporting files or by going to  'File'>'Edit metadata':

[image]

Note I think this uses [ID3v2.4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v2) tags (in Mp3), which are not compatible with some devices (and flippin Windows, even [Win8](http://arstechnica.com/features/2012/10/a-work-in-progress-the-windows-8-multimedia-experience/2/)...). Easytag however does have an options to use ID3v2.3, which should be compatible.

See also:

- http://wiki.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=MP3

Comment: There are many options available which will do batch editing. Unless you want to write the album artist, name, etc. in each of the songs...

Comment: @Rodrigo yes, you can save it as a template, then you just have to edit the title etc for each one

Comment: Please try puddletag and see the difference for yourself. When you have lots of subfolders in need of revision, puddletag is much faster than what you're suggesting.

Comment: @Rodrigo I think I just added this as an alternative to which people might already have! Saying this as I usually use `easytag` (you can upvote the [`puddletag` answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/161785/52956) btw)

Comment: Audacity 2.4.1 writes `ID3v2.3`, which is the most common and "safest" version. You don't have to worry about v2.4 incompatibility. (I verified it by using `eyed3` to read the metadata tags.)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.mp3 ; do
resto=$(echo "${i}" | sed 's/.mp3$//')
mid3v2 -t "${resto}" "${i}"
echo "${i}"
done
```