# MP3+FLAC tag editor for Linux

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, software-rec, mp3, flac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which mp3 tagging tool for Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4961/which-mp3-tagging-tool-for-linux)

Are there any good batch tag editors for Ubuntu/Fedora? Which one is the best?