# Add album-art cover to mp3/ogg file from command-line in batch mode?

Tags: command-line, audio

I am looking for a software in Linux, that will add the album-art/cover to each of the selected files in batch-mode. The album art is a jpg/png stored in my computer. It will be awesome if it can import from internet.

Currently I have tried both Rhythmbox and Banshee. I have also tried `lame` and `easytag`, but seems they do not support batch mode. `lame` is *not* adding the properties, but overwriting. (I know lame is the *only* command line s/w i have used so far).

So, basically I am looking for:

```
<some magic s/w> --picture=<my chosen picture> Music/Artist/*.mp3
```

That will add the picture to the metadata of the file, permanently.

Can you suggest me any such software?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

#### lame

Using `lame` you can do this using a little scripting:

```
$ lame --ti /path/to/file.jpg audio.mp3
```

If the files are named something like this you can make a shell script to do what you want:

```
for i in file1.mp3 file2.mp3 file3.mp3; do
  albart=$(echo $i | sed 's/.mp3/.jpg/')
  lame --ti /path/to/$albart $i
done
```

You can make the above slightly more compact and eliminate the need for `sed` by using `bash` to do it by having it remove the matching suffix:

```
...
albart="${i%.mp3}.jpg"
...
```

#### Picard/MusicBrainz

If you want to do this on a large scale I'd suggest using Picard which is the frontend tool for using the MusicBrainz database. There is a plugin to Picard called "Cover Art Downloader", which can do this to batches of your collection.

- [MusicBrainz](http://musicbrainz.org/)
- [Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard)
- [Picard Plugins](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard/Plugins)

The above doesn't appear to be command line driven however.

#### beets

Another option would be to use `beets`. This can be driven from the command-line and makes use of MusicBrainz database for sourcing the album art.

- http://beets.radbox.org/

You can either source the album art using[FetchArt Plugin](http://beets.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.1/plugins/fetchart.html) or embed it using the [EmbedArt Plugin](http://beets.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.1/plugins/embedart.html).

#### Other options?

Also take a look at this previously asked U&L Q&A titled: [Which mp3 tagging tool for Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4961/which-mp3-tagging-tool-for-linux). There are several alternative tools listed in this thread.

Comment: You can avoid the `sed` call with something like `albart="${i%.mp3}.jpg"`. More importantly, I just tested your lame command and got `lame: unrecognized option -i`...

Comment: @evilsoup - thanks, the switch was missing a dash. Should be `--ti ..`.

Comment: @evilsoup - also added your feedback on not using `sed`. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to remove the cover art with `lame`, too?

Comment: @Exeleration-G - no I wouldn't recommend using `lame` since it's actually an encoder. There are other tools for just manipulating the id3 tags of an mp3. You can use `id3v2 -r "APIC" *.mp3` or `eyeD3 --remove-all-images *.mp3` to remove any attached images.

Comment: Just a minor correction: it should be `eyeD3 --remove-images *.mp3`

Comment: @Exeleration-G - in my version it's "--remove-all-images   Remove all images from the tag". ver. 0.7.3-final.

Comment: @sim: This must be something that changed with the last versions. I'm using `eyeD3 0.6.18` on Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: @Exeleration-G - yeah no biggie, switches change, always consult a tool's usage: `eye3d --help` or man page.

Comment: I do not recommend this solution because it deletes the other id3 tags. The solution with `ffmpeg` is better.

Comment: FYI my version 3.99 does not have a "--ti" option (debian buster) - eyeD3 seems to be a good alternative.

Comment: I do not think that this should recommend using `lame --ti`.  AFAICT that will *lossily re-encode* the MP3 file, which isn't clear at all from this answer.

Comment: Fixed this answer, so the audio quality is not reduced: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/752036/115743

Answer (score 27):

One solution would be to use ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -i cover.jpg -map_metadata 0 -map 0 -map 1 output.mp3
```

You can put this in a for loop to do every MP3 in a directory:

```
for f in ./*.mp3; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -i cover.jpg -map_metadata 0 -map 0 -map 1 out-"${f#./}"; done
```

This will create a separate output file (so if you have a file called `foo.mp3`, you will end up with both `foo.mp3` and `out-foo.mp3`); this is because ffmpeg cannot write over its input. You can fix this with something like:

```
for f in ./*.mp3; do \
ffmpeg -i "$f" -i cover.jpg -map_metadata 0 -map 0 -map 1 out-"${f#./}" \
&& mv out-"${f#./}" "$f"; done
```

Using ffmpeg for this problem is a little bit like using a cruise missile to crack a nut. More specialised metadata-manipulating tools will certainly be able to do this in a cleaner, shorter command.

Comment: The ffmpeg command shown here will encode the audio. If you're converting from another format, that's fine, but if you just want to add art to an existing mp3 without re-encoding it, add `-acodec copy` after the `-map 1`.

Comment: This isn't working for me, any particular reason? I only get the mp3 file but no thumbnail. @jsd

Comment: Sorry @ChefPharaoh I don't know why it isn't working for you. I just tried doing wav->mp3 while adding art, and just adding art to an existing mp3 with those ffmpeg commands shown above. Both times it worked fine.

Comment: @evilsoup I'm not sure if I am doing something super evil or wrong, but I am able to modify my mp3 files in place using process substitution. Kinda simplifies this script and it seems to be super fast.

Comment: Worked like a treat, and I also found ffmpeg to be slightly faster than lame :)

Comment: ffmpeg can´t set a cover

Comment: Yes, `ffmpeg` can set a cover: confirmed with the command line from @evilsoup and the update from @jsd: `ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -i cover.jpg -map_metadata 0 -map 0 -map 1 -acodec copy out.mp3`

Answer (score 20):

For MP3:

```
eyeD3 --add-image="cover.jpg":FRONT_COVER "file.mp3"
```

For FLAC:

```
metaflac --import-picture-from="cover.jpg" "file.flac"
```

OGG/Vorbis seems to be [more complicated](https://superuser.com/questions/169151/embed-album-art-in-ogg-through-command-line-in-linux).

Answer (score 8):

Use mid3v2 from mutagen:

```
mid3v2 -p <image> <mp3>
```

Using lame or ffmpeg recodes the MP3 instead of only adding the image as meta-blob. And UI is not commandline.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [FancyAudio](https://rubygems.org/gems/fancy_audio) gem for this. It can add album art to mp3 files.
**Documentation** is available [**here**](http://www.singhajit.com/add-album-cover-to-mp3-file/).

**features**

1. add album art to single mp3 file
2. add album art to multiple mp3 files.

Below screen shot shows the output of fancy_audio when run in a folder containing an image and multiple mp3 files

[image]

Below screen shot shows the output of fancy_audio when run in a folder containing mp3 and image files

[image: This image shows the output of fancy_audio when run in a folder containing mp3 and image files]

Comment: This is easy, and works faster than `lame` when adding the same image to multiple mp3 files. You don't need to know Ruby ;) - this is a standalone script.

Answer (score 3):

eyeD3 **does not work with Unicode**.  If any non-ascii characters are in the .mp3 file name (or even in just an ancestor directory name, such as the Album directory), then it aborts.   LTA.

So you are out of luck if the Album or Song title is not written in English!

For example:

```
cp yoursong.mp3 /tmp/Странджанска.mp3
eyeD3 --add-image folder.jpg:FRONT_COVER Странджанска.mp3
```

Apparently eyeD3 wants to put the full path of the .mp3 file inside the .mp3 file and can't handle non-ascii characters.

```
Uncaught exception: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 5-16: ordinal not in range(128)
eyed3:ERROR: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 5-16: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback 
...(long traceback omitted)...
```

Comment: Why was this useful and helpful additional information downvoted?

Comment: eyed3 version 0.8.10 in Ubuntu 20.04 seems to work fine with UTF8 file names. I just used it on 21 files named "...Ungarische Tänze...mp3". The "ä" in the file name was not a problem. And I also copied a file to the cyrillic name in your example, and it worked fine with that too. My system is configured to use UTF8.

Answer (score 1):

OP states that he would prefer if the cover is downloaded from the web, and I just wrote a pretty okay script for that using `eye3D` and `sacad`, both installable from pip. `eye3D` is very useful for this purpose as it doesn't seem to re-encode audio and using the `--to-v2.4` flag handles any mp3 files, no matter the type of id3 tag. The script should be launched from the directory that contains the mp3 files. It can be run with no arguments, guessing the artist and album name from the id3 tags, or with manual names as arguments, e.g. `embedart "pink floyd" "dark side of the moon"`. It's written for the fish shell, but should easily be portable to bash if you change all the set commands to bash variable assigments.

```
function embedart
    if echo $argv | grep -q -e '-h'
       echo 'embedart "[Artist]" "[Album]"'
       return
    end

    if test $argv[1]
        set artist $argv[1]
        set album $argv[2]
    else
        set artist (eyed3 (ls *mp3 | head -1) | ggrep -oP "artist.*: \K.*" | head -1)
        if not test $artist
            echo "No artist found!"
            return
        end
        set album (eyed3 (ls *mp3 | head -1) | ggrep -oP "album.*: \K.*" | head -1)
        if not test $album
            echo "No album found!"
            return
        end
    end

    sacad $artist $album 350 cover.jpg -v warning 2> /dev/null > /dev/null
    eyeD3 --to-v2.4 --add-image "cover.jpg:FRONT_COVER" *mp3 -Q 2> /dev/null > /dev/null

    rm cover.jpg
    echo "Done!"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For convenient.

For /album/*.mp3

```
for f in */*.mp3
do 
    if [[ -e ${f%/*.mp3}/cover.jpg ]]; then
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -i ${f%/*.mp3}/cover.jpg -map_metadata 0 -map 0 -map 1 out-"${f#*/}" && mv out-"${f#*/}" "$f"
    else
    echo "=============================" 
    echo ${f%/*.mp3}/ #Find a folder which doesn't have cover.jpg
    fi
done
```

For "/album/cd 1/*.mp3"

```
for f in */*/*.mp3
do 
    if [[ -e ${f%/*.mp3}/cover.jpg ]]; then
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -i ${f%/*.mp3}/cover.jpg -map_metadata 0 -map 0 -map 1 out-"${f#*/*/}" && mv out-"${f#*/*/}" "$f"
    echo "=============================" 
    echo ${f%/*.mp3}/ #Find a folder which doesn't have cover.jpg
    fi
done
```

thanks to
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84956/401765

Answer (score -1):

This is amending the `Accepted Answer` which will *reduce the quality of high-fidelity recordings*.

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84963/115743

---

Example of how to keep maximum audio quality, versus be chopped and clobbered:

```
lame --preset insane -b 320 -h -V 0 --ti <image> <out>.mp3
```

Comment: Recoding to CBR 320 is clearly inappropriate for most existing MP3 streams.  Much better not to touch the audio data at all, as shown in the better answers.

Comment: All the `lame` answers reduce audio to 128. The purpose of the answer was to amend that already accepted answer, which degrades the audio.